# Notation for a certain kind of discrete measure

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is smooth, $Z=\{x: \phi(x)=0\}$ and $D\phi\neq0$ on $Z$. Is anyone familiar with use of the notation $dZ$ for the measure 
 $$\sum_{x \in Z} |D\phi(x)|\delta_x,$$
where $\delta_x$ is the Dirac measure at $x$? If so, can you explain it?

Comment: Does $f = \phi$?

Comment: Regarding your first question, I am not (familiar with this notation). Do you have any reference?

Comment: Just not to be confused: if smooth means just $C^\infty$?